# Using inner product property to determine if operator is an isomorphism.

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, inner-products, adjoint-operators

Let $\varphi$ be an operator on a $k$-vector space $V$ with an inner product $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$. Suppose that $\langle v,\varphi v\rangle = 0$ for every $v\in V$. If we take $k=\mathbb R$, is $\varphi$ is an isomorphism? What about if $k=\mathbb C$?

I think that both claims are false (in more generality). Can I get feedback on my proof and possibly alternate solutions (what happens in the infinite dimensional case)?

> Suppose that $V$ is finite dimensional. Then $\varphi$ has an adjoint $\varphi^\ast$. Then we obtain
>   $$
> \langle \varphi^\ast v, v \rangle = \langle v,\varphi v \rangle = 0
> $$
>   for every $v\in V$. Hence $\varphi^\ast v = 0$ for each $v$, which implies that $\varphi^\ast = 0$ and thus also that $\varphi^\ast(V)=\{0\}$. Since $\varphi^\ast(V)=(\ker\varphi)^\perp$, we obtain $\ker\varphi= V$. Thus $\varphi$ is not an isomorphism.

Answer (score 0):

If $k=\mathbb R,$ then rotation by $90$ degrees is a nonzero operator which sends every vector to a vector orthogonal to the original one.

If $k=\mathbb C,$ then it is indeed impossible, but not for the reasons you stated. It actually follows from some polarization identities, which write $\langle Tu, w\rangle$ in terms of inner products of the form $\langle Tv, v\rangle.$ Since all of the latter types of inner products are $0,$ all of the former type are also $0,$ from which you can conclude that $T=0.$

Comment: You mean T=0? Hm, so what is wrong with my proof?

Comment: You can't conclude from $\langle \varphi^*v, v\rangle=\langle v, \varphi v\rangle=0$ that $\varphi=0$.